# How to add php files to existing pages

Tags: php

I wanted to use php to forms and login pages that I already designed and my question is inoredr to access the php file should I run my html file by
Localhost/file.html.

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to rename your file.html in file.php and after that, you copy paste this with ne name of your file:

```
<?php include 'yourfile.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to your php file in two way:
You can use the `require_once` or `include` built in php functions.
It's important that you rename your .html file with the .php extension, otherwise it will never work.

Comment: @YeabsiraAshenafi - I would recommend that you start by doing some research and go through some PHP 101 tutorials.

Comment: Usually these two functions are used at the top of the page after the `<?php ?>` open tag. It depend on where you want to include your php files.